# AngularJS filter array by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, ionic-framework

I'm working on an `Ionic` hybrid app, but I'm quite new in `Javascript` / `AngularJS`.

I have this data structure:

```
  var objects= [
    {
      name: "o1",
      company: {
        id:2,
        fields: [1,6]
      }
    },
    {
      name: "o2",
      company: {
        id:2,
        fields: [3,4,5]
      }
    }
  ];

  var selectedFields= [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "f1",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "f2",
    }
  ];
```

I want to filter the `objects array` elements which contains the ids (in the attribute `company.fields`) corresponding with the elements contained in `selectedFields array`.

For example, in this case, we have 2 elements, `o1` and `o2`. `o1` contains the `fields` `1` and `6`, and `o2` contains the `fields` `3`, `4` and `5`.
The `selectedFields array` contains the `fields` with `ids` `1` and `2`, so in this case the filtered `object` should be the object `o1`.

That's what I have tried:

```
var filteredObjects = filterFilter(objects, selectedFields,function(o, sf){
      return angular.forEach(o.company.fields, function (field) {
        return field.id == sf.is;
      });
});
```

But it says that `o is undefined`.

and:

```
var result = [];
  angular.forEach(objects, function(o){
    angular.forEach(o.company.fields, function(f){
      angular.forEach(selectedFields, function(sf){
        if(sf.id == f.id) {
          result.push(o);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

But the `condition if(sf.id == f.id)` is never `true`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var test = objects.filter(function (o) {
    return selectedFields.some(function (i) {
        /*
            Some will return true if any of the elements return true
        */
        return i.id === o.company.id; 
    });
});
```

Essentially were filtering the Object array. `.Filter()` will create a new array with elements from the old one if its callback returns true. What `.some()` will do is return true if any any of its callbacks return true.

So `.some()` returns true if the id's match, which is passed into `.filter()` telling filter to add that element to the new array.

`.some()` is efficient in that it will stop iterating if it finds a matching result, callback that returns true. Whilst `.forEach()` will keep going and won't return a value.

http://jsfiddle.net/08tvmdyh/

Some Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

List of very usefully Array methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2

---

EDIT: I misread your question sorry.

```
var test = objects.filter(function (o) {
    return selectedFields.some(function (i) {
        /*
            Some will return true if any of the elements return true
        */
        return o.company.fields.indexOf(i.id) !== -1; //i.id === o.company.id; 
    });
});
```

Ive modified the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/08tvmdyh/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
    var filteredObjects = objects.filter(function(o){

        var fields = o.company.fields,
            matched = false;

        selectedFields.forEach(function(field){
          if(fields.indexOf(field.id) != -1){
            matched = true;
          }
        });

        return matched;
     });
```

First try to understand the following 3 native Array Functions built in Javascript :

```
    Array.prototype.filter;
    Array.prototype.forEach;
    Array.prototype.indexOf;
```